# How to put the item in DynamoDB with conditional expression that is not Primary Key

Tags: javascript, python, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

After generating a random `uuid` value I go ahead and assign it to the `item.uuid`:

```
let uuid = uuidv4();
let title = "Title 100"
```

```
let item = {
  uuid: uuid,
  title: title  
};
```

With the Dynamodb table where the Primary Key is the `item.uuid` attribute, I add the item to the table with:

```
let TABLE_NAME = "My Table Name";
let options = {};

let promise = dbClient.put_item({ Item: item, TableName: TABLE_NAME, ...options });
```

The new item is inserted into the Dynamodb table with the Primary Key `uuid` generated earlier.

Next, I want to add another item to the same table, with the same "title 101" title:

```
let uuid = uuidv4();
let title = "title 101"

let item = {
  uuid: uuid,
  title: title  
};
```

( both items will have the same `title`, but different `uuid` used as a Primary Key in a table).

Since I want to make sure, this item will be added only if no other items have the same "title 101" title, I use the `ConditionExpression`:

```
let options = {
    ConditionExpression: "#title <> :title",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { 
        "#title": "title" 
     },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":title" : "title 101"
    }
}

let promise = dbClient.put_item({ Item: item, TableName: TABLE_NAME, ...options });
promise
.then(res => {
  console.log('--------- SUCCESS --------');
  console.log(res);
  console.log('-----------------');
});
```

But regardless of the `ConditionExpression` used here, the DynamoDB goes ahead and adds a new item with the same `title` value.

Is there a way to use the conditional expression on an attribute (field) that is not a Primary Key?

Comment: It sounds to me like `title` needs to be unique. Why not make that the primary key and add the UUID as a non-key attribute. Add a GSI on UUID, if lookup by UUID is strictly needed. Then you can use `attribute_not_exists(#title)` to guarantee you won't overwrite a title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Condition Expressions` are only applicable for update/delete(not for create), i.e if an item already exists for the given primary key(PartitionKey + HashKey), then checks the result of condition expression and proceeds if it returns true. We still need to pass entire Primary Key.

We can try something with [scan + filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.FilterExpression), but we will end up reading entire table to find a row matching a non keyed attribute, which is in efficient and will cost a fortune if table is big.

so, best thing in this case is adding a Global Secondary Index on `title` and run two separate queries, First query on GSI by title to determine if record exists with matching title and put-item if doesn't exist.

Comment: There will be race conditions here, of course, potentially resulting in duplicate titles. You might be able to address these with a transaction including a ConditionCheck.